Can't remove folder shortcut left behind by program I uninstalled
I had an old Daemon Tools program installed on my PC. It is for mounting ISOs as virtual drives and when installed automatically creates an explorer shortcut named "IMAGE CATALOG" in which to store disk images.
I uninstalled Daemon Tools using Revo Uninstaller but the shortcut was left behind in Explorer as well as on my Desktop, and I can't remove it no matter what I tried:

There's no option to delete the desktop icon
I tried "cleaning" the registry with WiseCleaner as well as CCleaner
I tried restoring a *.reg registry backup I had, but Registry Editor wouldn't import it, returning an error.

I don't want to format my PC or reinstall Windows.
I'm hoping someone can tell me the Windows registry paths where both Desktop and Explorer quick shortcuts are stored.  I'm hoping I can remove the shortcuts by editing the registry.


